# Is there a way to run a command line "inside" a symlink?

Tags: windows, symlink

I have a symlink named `example.avi` that points to a real `example.avi` video file.  When a program tries opens the symlink, it really opens the video file.  But now I would like execute a command line whenever a program tries to open the symlink file.

Is that possible?

ps: windows

Comment: Are there symlinks in Windows?  There are symlinks in Linux and Mac.  There are shortcuts in Windows.  If you really mean symlink, then do you really mean dos commands?  Perhaps you mean bash?  Simply, what OS are you talking about?

Comment: @BuvinJ: Windows has had symlinks since the release of Windows 2000, roughly 16 years ago.

Comment: Ok.  I never heard of a Windows symlink.  I guess I should have then!

Comment: I found an interesting Super User thread on the subject. http://superuser.com/questions/253935/what-is-the-difference-between-symbolic-link-and-shortcut At least one popular answer there said they aren't commonly used in Windows like they are in Linux.

Comment: yes, I'm in windows enviroment

Comment: @BuvinJ: they're rarely useful.  In most use cases either a junction point or a shortcut will serve better.  But they do exist.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in way of creating a symlink or other file system object that causes a command to be executed when it is opened by an application.

It should in principle be possible to do this with a file system filter driver.  But that's very complicated.  I believe there are some third-party tools to simplify this sort of task, but I don't have any experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

While I am clearly ignorant on the subject of symlinks in Windows (see my comments on your question).  I just played with it and proved that you could basically do this by symlinking to a wrapper for your avi.  I.e. symlink to an exe or a batch file, etc. which does what you want and then opens the avi.  Here's a test I ran with txt files and notepad:

Create a file called test.txt with some text.  Create a file next to it called test.bat.  Here's the batch:

```
notepad test.txt
```

When you run the batch, it just opens the txt in notepad.

Then I added a symlink:

```
mklink test2.txt test.bat
```

Now, when I type test2.txt in the command prompt, or double click on it, it runs the batch and opens the test.txt file.  Obviously, you can use the same basic logic.  It doesn't, however, fire the batch off when I open the symlink in Notepad++.  It just opens to batch for editing instead.

Of course, maybe you don't want a second file, in which case you need to literally embed your avi in some wrapper.  I guess we ned to know more about what you want to do.  It sounds like an attempt at malware hidden in a video to me...

Comment: That will work if the user double-clicks the symlink.  I *think* the OP wanted it to work when an application opens the file, e.g., the user launches Media Player and uses File->Open.  (But I could be mistaken.)

Comment: Right.  I explained that in my answer.  The question is why?